# Android Studio File Explorer not working on Marshmallow (Nexus devices)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

After updating my Nexus 5 and then my Nexus 7 to Marshmallow, it seems I'm no longer able to access the device storage.

Previously, from the Android Studio Device Monitor's File Explorer I could access mnt/shell/emulated/0 to access the device's "external" storage.

Now, with Marshmallow, it seems mnt/shell is completely gone. Is there any way to access this same storage location?

Comment: still can't find a solution for this either

Comment: I have the same problem, it can browse but can not drill down the directory forexample /storage/emulated/0 can not be accessed

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `/mnt/user/0/primary`? 
It works perfectly fine on G4 and Nexus 6 running Marshmallow.

Comment: I can get down to /mnt/user/0 but it appears to be empty.

Comment: @whitaay That's weird.
Another option is `/storage/self/primary/`, You can check that - it's another location pointing to, as You called it, 'external' storage.